# How to make a public Stopwatch in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, public, stopwatch

I'm fairly new to C#, so forgive me if I make a stupid mistake or this question is obvious. I'm trying to make a program that can make multiple instances of a timer, which is displayed in a datagridview. Basically, every row has to have its own timer, which can be controlled via two buttons within the same row.

Currently I have this code:

```
public void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        }
```

I need to be able to access the stopwatch and turn it off from within a different function. The problem is that I can't declare the stopwatch as a global variable in the beginning, because I have to constantly create a new stopwatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a single Stopwatch, create a globally available indexed collection of Stopwatches (e.g. Dictionary). Then, in your click operation you can create a new one if one does not already exist for the row.

Note: you will need to key the Dictionary off some value which is unique to each row so that you can reference it at a future point.

Comment: Ok, thanks! This sounds like the thing I need. I've never heard of Dictionaries before but I'll try it!

Comment: You will find `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. There may be more efficient collections, but I find this to be the most straightforward. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just declare it as global.
when u want to create a new, just stopwatch=new Stopwatch();